# maven external jar dependency

Tags: java, maven, import

I am trying to use a jar given by my teacher in my code. So I placed the jar in a lib directory in my project and ran this command :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/IDLogger.jar -DgroupId=IDLogger -DartifactId=IDLogger -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Everything is fine.

Then I add the dependency to the pom :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>IDLogger</groupId>
   <artifactId>IDLogger</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But then when I try to use the jar, the compilation fails and tells me that the symbol(the class) can't be found. I even tried adding an import statement :

```
import IDLogger.IDLogger;
```

but it tells me that there is no such package.

How can I use this jar in my code in maven?

This is the code :

```
IDLogger logger = IDLogger.getInstance(); 

...

logger.logID(id);
```

I get the symbol `IDLogger` not found error

This is as much as I know about this custom jar...

Comment: Import statement consists of java package name and java class name, it has nothing to do with groupId and artifactId of the maven dependency. The import you mentioned would only work if you wanted to use IDLogger class from IDLogger package. The error looks like you didn't import the right class. What code creates the error?

Comment: edited to add the code

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Does it compile on the command line?

Comment: Ok so to use the IDLogger symbol in code you need to have the import statement, otherwise the symbol is unknown. You said that when you added the import it said there is no `IDLogger` package which may be true. Are you sure that IDLogger class is in the IDlogger package? Did your teacher provide any documentation or example code that would imply that?

Comment: yes it's all the info I have... The rest of the class are using Eclipse and the instructions said that they should just add it as a dependency to the Eclipse project. No import statement specified. I really want to only stick to maven and it's the last thing I need to get to work before being done with this project...

Comment: A jar file is just an archive (like a zip file), so you can easily inspect it to figure out which classes are in there and in which package the class `IDLogger` is located.

Comment: Or you can ask your friends for the import that Eclipse is auto-adding for them :-) Programming in java without IDE is a pain, you can use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate eclipse project and have the best of both worlds (or M2E eclipse plugin).

Comment: ok thank to hotzst I was able to find the package (ca.etsmtl.log.util.IDLogger)

Comment: And I can now compile! but I get a runtime exception. It looks like it is trying to find a class file but I am using a jar...

Comment: @AntoineLev how do you run it? If you want to run it from maven you should use maven exec plugin. If you just run your jar manually you need to add the teacher's jar to the java classpath in the command line option.

Comment: Yes I placed the jar in the extension directory of my java installation and now I can run it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your lib in system scope :

```
1. add in your project :

    Your Project/lib 
                +IDLogger.jar

2. in your pom :

     <dependency>
       <groupId>IDLogger</groupId>
       <artifactId>IDLogger</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/IDLogger.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
```